# How to skip N nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes

I have a code:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").next().next().find(".fileinfo-td:first > div");
```

Is any method which can skip N nodes and can be used instead of next().next();

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you show corresponding html and give an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: any html, i need shorthand of next().next(), or something like next().next().next().next(), - is an ability in jquery to replace that sequence?

Comment: [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) might help.

Comment: Since you're dealing with `parents` and `find`, it means than you are doing something rather complex. It would be better if you can provide us the HTML of your document and also tell us what do you want to achieve, so that we can give the best (more performant) answer possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").nextAll(":eq(1)").find(".fileinfo-td:first > div");
```

Comment: +1 from me - probably the most correct one. Though I don't like `parents("tr:first")` and not sure what actually OP wanted to express by that